# Loop issue displaying data in TXT file with BATCH programming

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

HI,

I want to display datas in text file. Here i have Listfile.txt and want to display each line using batch file. How to do this with looping.
Below is my code

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (Listfile.txt) do (
  set /a N+=1
  set v!N!=%%a
)
set hostname=!v1!
echo %hostname%
pause
```

Data in `Listfile.txt`:

```
4mLinuxMachine.cpp
ShutdownPanel.cpp
windows.cpp
```

How to display each using hostname variable

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display each line of the text file, try this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1"  %%a IN (Listfile.txt) DO (
  ECHO %%a
)
```

Comment: My intention is to store in each line in hostname and hav eto print in for loop

Comment: Side note: This will loop over every *non-empty* line in the file.